# Toggle Classes in Svelte Component

Tags: javascript, html, css, svelte, svelte-component

Consider this Svelte code:

https://svelte.dev/repl/e3ea17e8e09044999bf7cb4bc882adea?version=3.19.2

How can I adjust this so that each button can be toggled independently?
As you can see it currently toggles all of the buttons :(

Comment: Seems like you have modified the code in the REPL since asking? Would be nice for visitors from the future to post the relevant code in the question. SO likes having its threads self contained and not dependent on the content of external links that can change ;)

Comment: yeah.. no probs.. i'll revert it and start a new repl for what i'm working on :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to maintain the state for each button like so:

```
<script>let active = {button1: false, button2: false, button3: false};</script>

<style>.active {background-color: #ff3e00; color: white;}</style>

<button class:active="{active.button1}" on:click="{() => active.button1 = !active.button1}">foo</button>
<button class:active="{active.button2}" on:click="{() => active.button2 = !active.button2}">bar</button>
<button class:active="{active.button3}" on:click="{() => active.button3 = !active.button3}">baz</button>
```

Comment: Well it is pretty unavoidable given that you need to monitor 3 button states. :) Do accept if the answer helped.

Comment: i've just been told on the svelte discord that you can do this with a button component and then avoid doing the above. let me test this first before accepting the answer

Comment: While making a Button component is probably a good advice (or maybe overkill, if it's just to add a class?), I think this really answers the initial question.

Answer (score 1):

So for those wanting a more in-depth answer to the above, I've created a svelte button component that allows toggling and opening of links at this REPL

https://svelte.dev/repl/c5b48ef759d045d08d17b5f11b74e82e?version=3.19.2

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to either having to make a new component or creating a variable for tracking is to use the class that you want to toggle. As an example:

```
element.classList.toggle('className');
```

Comment: The if/else block could be simplified to just `classList.toggle(className)`

Comment: Thank you! That's much nicer. Updated answer for future viewers